# how BufferedInputStream.available works?

Tags: java

```
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("dd.txt");
        BufferedInputStream bufi= new BufferedInputStream(in);
        System.out.println(bufi.available());
        int half =bufi.available()/2;
        bufi.skip(half);
        System.out.println(bufi.available());
```

output:

7

4

in "dd.txt" there is 1234567

but why bufi can skip before I use bufi.read(),I mean when the data is sent to input stream?

Comment: Look at the source code ...

Answer (score 0):

It works by adding the number of bytes currently buffered, possibly zero, to the value returned by the `available()` method of the wrapped stream. In this case the wrapped stream is a `FileInputStream`, whose `available()` method returns, arguably incorrectly, the number of bytes remaining to be read in the file.

There is no reason why `skip()` should not be possible prior to a `read()`. Data is never 'sent t an imoitbstream'. It is read *by* an input stream.

Comment: so when does  input stream read the data in file?Right after FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("dd.txt");
BufferedInputStream bufi= new BufferedInputStream(in);
these two sentences?